# invert n different random bits in int

Tags: c++, math, random, bit

How could i efficiently invert *n* bits in unsigned int *x*? Each bit must be picked randomly. Also it must be picked only once. Hamming distance between *x* and returned result must equals *n*. Is there an O(*n*) solution?

```
// rnd_engine is kind of std::minstd_rand
template< typename rnd_engine >
unsigned int invert_bits( unsigned int x, unsigned int n, rnd_engine& rndEngine ) {
   assert( n <= sizeof( x ) * 4 );
   return // your ideas?
}
```

Comment: Please add the appropriate language tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do the following: [Replace `randInt(n+1)` with whatever function returns a random integer in the interval `[0,n]` inclusive.

1. Define a variable `mask` with a bit count of exactly `n`: `unsigned int mask = (1<<n)-1;`. This is `O(1)`
2. Perform a slightly modified version of the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm); Loop `int i = 0; i<n; i++`, then swap bits at `i` and `rndEngine::randInt(i+1)` in `mask`. This is `O(n)`.
3. `return x ^ mask`. This flips the bits that are set in `mask`; which are `n` shuffled bits. This is `O(1)`.

The operation is `O(n)` assuming `randInt` (or whatever) is `O(1)`.